# How to deserialize JSON to Map object using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, dictionary, jackson

I have a JSON with a tag that contains arbitrary key and value types that I want to read into a map within its POJO in Java. The map would be a String to something like JsonValue or JsonNode. I'm using the object mapper to parse the json.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to set up my POJO to accomplish this with Jackson? Or a better way to go about this?

Json Example:

```
{
    "thing": "name",
    "params": {
        "foo": 45.5,
        "key": "value"
    }
}
```

Mapping Methods:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyClasst = objectMapper.readValue(json, MyClass.class);
```

My POJO:

```
public class MyClass {
    private String thing;
    private Map<String, SOMETHING> params;

    public String getThing(){
        return thing;
    }

    public void setThing(String thing) {
        this.thing = thing;
    }

    public Map<String, SOMETHING> getParams(){
        return params;
    }

    public void setParams(Map<String, SOMETHING> params) {
        this.params = params;
    }
}
```

Comment: `"foo": 45.5` what is this signify ?

Comment: It's just to show that the `params` field has more than one key, each with arbitrary value types (`foo` being a double, and `key` being a string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your key is always be `String` type for following JSON,

```
"params": {
        "foo": 45.5,
        "key": "value"
    }
```

You should use your map value as `Object`, since value can be `String`, `Double` or anything else.

```
private Map<String, Object> params;
```

Comment: I think that could work. I was hesitant to do this because some of the values could be json objects. But after testing it, it looks like those would become HashMaps, continuing the cycle. Thanks.

Comment: @user3499973 Yes, just for side note, `Object` is superclass, so you won't any issue with any object